# Visual block. Some right-end selections seem impossible

Tags: visual-mode, visual-block

I want to use visual block mode (ctl-v) to select all the comments but none of the code:

```
a = 1             // short comment
b = 2             // this one is a longer comment
c = 3             // shortest
```

My selection is marked with X characters here. Notice that if I start at the top-left my selection is unsatisfactory:

```
a = 1             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
b = 2             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX longer comment
c = 3             XXXXXXXXXXX
```

If I start middle-left I lose either the first or third line:

```
a = 1             // short comment
b = 2             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
c = 3             XXXXXXXXXXX
```

And so on. I'm missing something here. What is the secret? I've tried :help and searched here and Google.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The secret is to press `$` after you have expanded your block vertically:

```
<C-v>jj$
```

or to press `$` before expanding your block vertically:

```
<C-v>$jj
```

Well, `$` is the secret.

<sup><sup><sup>…which is not *that* surprising, after all.</sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 6):

One (*) secret is:

```
set virtualedit=block
```

... in your `vimrc` :)

(`:h virtualedit` will explain everything).

A disadvantage of this method: when yanking, you get trailing spaces on the shorter lines.

(*) The other is in the answer provided by @[romainl](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/54/romainl).

---

BTW, for **the secret of the golden rivet**, see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vf6FRtmZewg) instead.

Comment: I've ticked @romainl but your answer was interesting too, and the clip :)

Comment: You chose well :)